# AVPlayerViewController change video quality

Tags: iphone, swift, swift3

I am currently working on HTTP Live streaming video with `AVPlayerViewController / AVPlayer`

I am playing a video with `.m38u` file support.

My question is how to change video quality like `YouTube`. Is there any way to change video quality ? I haven't found any link nor tutorial (in swift 3)

Comment: did u get any solution?

Comment: did u get any solution?